# Powered USB Hub Requirements

Tags: pi-4, usb-hub

I dont plan on powering my Pi through a USB hub, but I do intend on hooking up some HDD's to a powered hub since everything I see so far seems to indicate that the pi cant power multiple HDD's.

If I'm just using the hub for powering/using the HDD's, do I need to worry about stuff like power feedback, the device drivers, etc?

I was looking at getting a [basic amazon one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DQFGH80) but didn't want to run any risk to hurting my pi. Would that one suffice? I couldn't find any reccomendations that were current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backfeed shouldn't harm anything, though your Pi 4 may remain partially on if the powered hub is on.

The hub *should* be plug-n-play, and the common drivers ship pre-installed.